# POST using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, api, post, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a back-end API connected to a front-end interface to make a worm walks up and down in a hole (is a test).
But I'm tottaly stuck  making the POST to API from a form. Using Bootstrap

my form

```html
<div>
    <h2>Insira os dados para a movimentação</h2>
    <form method="POST" action="localhost:3000/move/data" role="form" id="dataForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="holeSize">Comprimento:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control"  id="holeSize" value="20"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="moveForward">Avanço:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="moveForward" value="5"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="moveBackward">Recuo:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="moveBackward" value="3"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendData()">Start</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

And my move.js

```
const form = document.getElementById("dataForm");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    sendData();
})

function sendData() {
    console.log('start')
    document.getElementById('worm').style.top = "300px";

    const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    const FD = new FormData(form);


    XHR.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
        alert(event.target.responseText);
    });

    XHR.addEventListener("error", function (event) {
        alert('Oops! algo deu errado');
    });

    XHR.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/move/data");

    XHR.send(FD);

}
```

I Made this "document.getElementById('worm').style.top = "300px";" to check if the click on button worked, the DIV moves in my screen (transition OK) but no post was made from it.

EDIT ->
After a suggestion, I called the move.js script at the end of my

the it starts to work.

But the form is going blank, I made a

```
        let movement = req.body;
        console.log(movement);
```

and returns simple {}

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Check your browser console for errors. I'd say it's highly likely this is a CORS problem

Comment: Also, Bootstrap is a UI library. You are attempting to make a POST request using plain old JavaScript

Comment: A Friend simply put the <script> to end of my code and it worked.

Now I'm stuck because the body of the request is going with no information just a {}

Comment: Have you configured your server-side code (assuming Express) to handle `multipart/form-data` requests? Because that's what you're sending it

Comment: Why do you have `onclick="sendData()"` and `form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {` which calls sendData? Pick one....

Comment: Your inputs do not have name attributes.

Comment: @epascarello I already set the names.
And removed the event listener.

Probably need to enable multipart/form-data requests now.

Thanks for the tips Guys. I will try to fix and notify you what works

Answer (score 0):

After move the  from my header to bottom of my body and adding this to my custom-express.js

```
    let upload  = multer();

    app.use(cors());
// for parsing application/json
    app.use(express.json());

// for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// for parsing multipart/form-data
    app.use(upload.array());
    app.use(express.static('public'));
```

the post worked.

Thanks for the tips guys.